# Change the name of a tab

Tags: 7, organic-groups, navigation

I have a group made from Organic groups, and it has these two tabs.

[image]

I want to change the name of "View", but can't figure out where to do that.

Even better would be if I could delete that little menu. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module should do everything you need.

> Tab Tamer is an administration utility that provides easy re-ordering,
>   hiding, and deactivation of tabs and subtabs. You can also rename tab
>   labels.

Comment: What if i need to change the title for a particular content type and not everything on the site ?

Comment: @Jayaram It'd be better if you opened a new question with your use case.  That way other people could benefit :)